# SCSS concatenation with selectors

Tags: css, loops, sass

What I'm trying to achieve, is to simply loop over and create a selector based on how many columns a variable has.

```
$numberOfColumns: 16;
.gridContainer {
  @for $i from 1 through $numberOfColumns {
    .grid_#{$i} @if $i != $numberOfColumns {,}
    {position:relative;}        
  }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work.

I'm trying to output something like this:

```
.grid_1,.grid_2,.grid_3,.grid_4,.grid_5,.grid_6,.grid_7,.grid_8,.grid_9,.grid_10,.grid_11,.grid_12,.grid_13,.grid_14,.grid_15,.grid_16 {position:relative;}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use `join` to create a variable containing all the comma-separated classes and use that afterwards. Here is how:

```
$numberOfColumns: 16;

$classes: ();
@for $i from 1 through $numberOfColumns {
    $classes: join($classes, unquote(".grid_#{$i} "), comma);
}

.gridContainer {
    #{$classes} { position:relative; }
}
```

Produced output:

```
.gridContainer .grid_1, .gridContainer .grid_2, .gridContainer .grid_3, .gridContainer .grid_4, .gridContainer .grid_5, .gridContainer .grid_6, .gridContainer .grid_7, .gridContainer .grid_8, .gridContainer .grid_9, .gridContainer .grid_10, .gridContainer .grid_11, .gridContainer .grid_12, .gridContainer .grid_13, .gridContainer .grid_14, .gridContainer .grid_15, .gridContainer .grid_16 {
    position:relative;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://codepen.io/alp82/pen/IuFlz)

Here is a more thorough explanation of the same concept: http://portfolio.miphe.com/showcase/sass-dry-selectors/

Comment: Heads up, it's now 7 years later, both your links are broken.

Answer (score 4):

A situation like this typically calls for using a **placeholder selector**:

> Sometimes you’ll write styles for a class that you only ever want to `@extend`, and never want to use directly in your HTML. This is especially true when writing a Sass library, where you may provide styles for users to `@extend` if they need and ignore if they don’t.
>
> [...]
>
> Placeholder selectors look like class and id selectors, except the `#` or `.` is replaced by `%`. They can be used anywhere a class or id could, and on their own they prevent rulesets from being rendered to CSS.

[placeholders @ sass-lang.com](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders)

---

With a placeholder selector, you can collect all of the properties that are common to *all* grid columns in a single rule:

```
%grid-column {
  // common column properties...
}
```

Then use the `@extend` directive to add `.grid-container .grid-i` selectors to the placeholder rule:

```
$num-grid-cols: 2;
.grid-container {
  @for $i from 1 through $num-grid-cols {
    .grid-#{$i} {
      @extend %grid-column;
      // grid-$i specific properties...
    }
  }
}
```

The resultant CSS will look like this:

```
.grid-container .grid-1, .grid-container .grid-2 {
  // common column properties... 
}

.grid-container .grid-1 {
  // grid-1 specific properties... 
}

.grid-container .grid-2 {
  // grid-2 specific properties... 
}
```